# Configuring cluster aware routers with maximum total number of instances

Tags: akka, akka.net, akka-cluster

We want to spawn up to N instances of routees in Akka cluster, and our original thought was to use cluster-aware pool routers. The downside of this approach is that then the router needs to be spawned as a cluster singleton, and if we don't make it a singleton then we will end up with M routers (where M is a number of nodes), each managing its own pool of N instances, and we want the total number of instances in the whole system to be N, not M*N.

What looked like a straightforward task, doesn't seem to be possible in Akka cluster, but I want to confirm it. So, given the maximum total number of instances, is it possible to configure its router not to be a singleton, so routers will be created on different nodes and they will share the same pool of routees?

Comment: This may not be the ideal use case of this feature, but it should be achievable with cluster sharding - use 1-1 mapping between sharding entity and shard, then split shard-id/entity-id into modulo N. Unless N is big, this should not be a problem.

Comment: Ha. This should work. It's not canonical case for cluster sharding but solves the case. Thanks!